# Creating a plot of columns against a single column in R

Tags: r

In my table below, I'm attempting to create a scatterplot between `X3-X3.6` against the risk score to see if there is any correlation. I have all this data stored in a data frame.

I'm new to R. What is the best way to extract this data? I'm using `plot` and `pairs` and multiple lines of code to extract different columns and it's getting extremely messy.

## Attempt

```
plot(cancerData[2], cancerData[3])
```

which corresponds to risk score col in Risk.Score and X3.GAL

This results in the following error:

```
Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code even if it didn't work. Also, provide [reproducible example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Updated the plot code in the original

Comment: What do you mean problem in the analysis? I'm getting an error with the plot command.

Comment: Have you tried `plot(as.numeric(cancerData[,2]), as.numeric(cancerData[,3]))`? Your values are aligned as if they were characters...

Comment: Did you just want to plot `plot(cancerData[,3], cancerData[,4])` ? Or a series of pairwise plots?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop to create all of the different plots. If your data frame was named "data" for code for the loop would look something like this:

```
# iterate the loop for variables x3 to the end
for (variable in names(data)[3:ncol(data)]) {
  # plot rating versus the variable of the iteration
  # in order to reference the column you can paste the variable name to "data$" and evaluate the text
  plot( data$rating, eval(parse( text = paste0("data$", variable))) )
}
```

You could also perform the same loop but instead referring to column positions

```
for ( variable in 3:ncol(data) ) {
plot( data$rating, unlist(data[ ,variable]) )
}
```

You could also just use the corrplot library to create a correlation matrix with the data frame. Looping to create scatter plots is going to give you a lot of output. If you get rid of erroneous columns you could just do:

```
plot(data)
```

This will create a scatter plot matrix but the plots will be small with many variables so it would be tough to read.